# Appending data from .txt to an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, append

I have two .txt files. They have exactly same format and columns.

The first .txt file looks like this:

[image]

And this is the VBA code I am using to export the data from the first .txt file to an excel sheet (shared by @FaneDuru)

```
Sub CopyLessColumns()
 Dim strSpec As String, i As Long, colToRet As Long
 Dim arrSp As Variant, arrRez() As String, arrInt As Variant, j As Long
 Dim fso As Object, txtStr As Object, strText As String

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strSpec = "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\Input.txt"
  If Dir(strSpec) <> "" Then                   
    Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(strSpec)
        strText = txtStr.ReadAll
    txtStr.Close
 End If

  arrSp = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
  colToRet = 5                             'Number of columns you need
  ReDim arrRez(UBound(arrSp), colToRet - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSp)
    arrInt = Split(arrSp(i), vbTab)
    If UBound(arrInt) > colToRet - 1 Then
        For j = 0 To colToRet - 1
            arrRez(i, j) = arrInt(j)
        Next j
    End If
  Next i
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arrRez, 1) + 1, UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1)).Value = arrRez
End Sub
```

After I run the code above, my excel sheet will look like this:

[image]

But I am not sure how to append data from the second .txt file to my existing spreadsheet.

Below is my second .txt file. Same format, same column numbers, just different data.

[image]

I want to append data from the second .txt file to my spreadsheet, so it can look like this

[image]

As you can see, when I import the second .txt file, I want to skip the header row, and directly import the data below the first row.

In addition, the row number of the first .txt file can change any time, so I cannot just use the exact same code and simply change the last line from

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(UBound(arrRez, 1) + 1, UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1)).Value = arrRez
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(UBound(arrRez, 1) + 1, UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1)).Value = arrRez
```

I also tried to find the last row by using

```
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then, change the last line to

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(UBound(arrRez, 1) + 1, UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1)).Value = arrRez
```

But that didn't work either. It will just overwrite the last row of the existing data on the spreadsheet with the header row in the second .txt file

I tried to look up online, but didn’t find anything similar to what I am trying to do here, So, any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207556/discussion-on-question-by-emmag-appending-data-from-txt-to-an-excel-sheet).

Comment: @EmmaG: Please use my last code (answer). I had some time and I made a code able to do what you need independent of text files number to be processed. No need of two separate codes...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for the new code. These comments are really helping me to understand what you are doing. But, just to clarify...the reason I used two separate codes/subs is because I have two .txt files. Their paths are different. I see your new code can automatically append data from the second txt file as long as I change the path, so thank you, it's definitely helpful

Comment: @EmmaG:  I commented all the code in order to help you understand it. I will give you a challenge: Make the `Sub` to receive a string parameter (strSpec), which to be passed from another sub, where you will call this one twice, but using different paths... And take care to comment/delete the line `strSpec = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\TextFileTabDel.txt"`...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, although slightly different, but that's actually pretty much the same thing I am doing reseach on right now. For my next step, I am trying to put the import/append code into a loop function. Prompt the user to select files, then keep doing Importing/appending until the users says stop. I will try :)

Comment: @EmmaG: If you do what I suggested, you can simply locate all your files in one folder and then create a piece of code to loop between all text files in that location and call the sub with their path like function parameter...

Comment: Interesting...didn't know you could do that in vba. This is probably gonna take a long time, but hopefully I can figure it out before the end of this month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code version! It is the same for as many text files you want to load. It will load the table headers only ones (When the sheet is empty) and then only data, without headers:

```
Private Sub CopyLessColumns() 'it copies less columns than the txt file has
 Dim strSpec As String, i As Long, colToRet As Long, lastR As Long
 Dim arrSp As Variant, arrRez() As String, arrInt As Variant, j As Long, k As Long
 Dim fso As Object, txtStr As Object, strText As String 'no need of any reference

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strSpec = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\TextFileTabDel.txt"
  If Dir(strSpec) <> "" Then 'check if file exists
    Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(strSpec)
        strText = txtStr.ReadAll
    txtStr.Close
  End If
  arrSp = Split(strText, vbCrLf)

    colToRet = 5 'Number of columns to be returned
    lastR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A:A
    'arrRez is dimensioned from 0 to UBound(arrSp) only for lastR = 1
    ReDim arrRez(IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1) To UBound(arrSp), colToRet - 1)
    For i = IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1) To UBound(arrSp) 'Only in case of larR = 1, the
                                                  'head of the table is load in arr
      arrInt = Split(arrSp(i), vbTab)  'each strText line is split in an array
      If UBound(arrInt) > colToRet - 1 Then
          For j = 0 To colToRet - 1
              arrRez(i, j) = arrInt(j) 'each array element is loaded in the arrRez
          Next j
      End If
    Next i
    'The array is dropped in the dedicated range (calculated using Resize):
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrRez, 1), _
                                                UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1).Value = arrRez
End Sub
```